# Do the std::vector member function resize work different than

Tags: c++, stdvector

I was looking at ways to make space for vectors and I found two ways to do what I think is the same thing.

```
std::vector<int> v1(n);
```

and

```
std::vector<int> v2;
v2.resize(n);
```

I was wondering if there is a difference in these. Would most compilers compile both of these into the same code? Am I right to assume that there would only be a performance difference between the two if there was code that inserts items into v2 in between it's declaration and calling resize on it?

Comment: If you know the size up front, why not declare it at that point? `resize` is intended for cases where you find out later. Less code, more concise.

Comment: The "performance difference" will be zero for all practical purposes. Any extra work that _might_ occur when you construct and resize the vector in two steps instead of one, is orders of magnitude faster than the resulting memory allocation that is common to both approaches. TLDR; write the cleanest code (first option), and direct your performance concerns to stuff that is actually measurable.

Comment: You might consider `reserve` instead of `resize`. The latter allocates and initializes the vector. With the former, you just add ints with `push_back`. This reduces the redundant initialization but also means you can't use indexes `[]` until you have populated the vector.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, a vector implementation would look a little bit like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class vector {
public:

  vector()
    : begin(0), end(0) {}

  vector(size_t s) {
     begin = new T[s];
     end = begin + s;

     // default construct each element
     for(size_t i = s; i < size(); ++i) {
        begin[i] = T();
     }
  }


  void resize(size_t s) {
     // if the array is shrinking
     if(s < size()) {
        // destroy the elements we're about to remove
        for(size_t i = s; i < size(); ++i) {
           begin[i].~T();
        }
        // shrink array without deallocating
        end = begin + s;
     }
     else
     // if growing
     if(s > size()) {
        // allocate a new array
        T* new_array = new T[s];
    
        // copy in old elements
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
           new_array[i] = T(begin[i]);
        }

        // default construct new elements
        for(size_t i = size(); i < s; ++i) {
           new_array[i] = T();
        }
    
        // destroy old array
        for(size_t i = 0; s < size(); ++s) {
           begin[i].~T();
        }

        // free old memory
        delete [] begin;
    
        // update pointers
        end = new_array + s;
        begin = new_array;
     }
  }


  size_t size() const {
    return end - begin;
  }

  T* begin;
  T* end;
};
```

(Using new/delete in here rather than global new/delete is a bit wrong, but internal details are not overly important here)

The short answer: prefer `std::vector v1(n);`

The long answer: They *might* result in the same code being generated, but as with all templates, this will depend on your compiler, the build flags you've specified, and the compilation unit being compiled.

It's possible that the compiler will effectively inline the calls, such that calling resize will be no different from direct construction with the size. There are however cases where this won't occur *(e.g. you've forcibly exported a std::vector specialisation from a DLL, or the frequency of calls to resize within your current compilation unit persuades the compiler that generating function calls is a better around option than inlining)*.

If you want to initialise a vector to an initial size, calling the appropriate constructor is the best approach....

Comment: I like the idea of using a snippet of code to better explain the behavior of the `resize(size_type)` member function and the overloaded constructor, but the example implementation lacks destructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment operator, and other functions and members that are a core part of the `std::vector` container's interface.
I recommend using snippets of the GCC implementation code (`stl_vector.h`, `vector.tcc`) as example and then posting some comments to explain their behavior.